# Language shift because of contact or interest

Tags: sociolinguistics, language-contact

Are there any examples of language shift, where population A changes language because of contacts with population B? I am not looking about examples where population A was conquered or colonized by B. I am looking for examples where population A had an interest in changing to the language of population B, because of extensive contacts, social status etc.

Comment: That's pretty much how English is spreading all over the world now.

Comment: It's certainly how it spread through North America.

Comment: Ok, maybe I should rephrase my question. English spread because of colonialism etc. I am looking for a case where this shift happened because of non-violent events or foreign rule.

Comment: I live in a formerly French-speaking, now English-speaking city which passed from French to US control by purchase, not conquest or colonization.

Comment: Completely non-violently, a large number of European graduates have learnt to speak English. The primary factors are Hollywood and the internet. Less prominently, but more importantly, English has become the lingua franca of academia.

Comment: Easiest example: In the history of China, there were a few times that non-Chinese races (considered barbarians in the Chinese language) invaded from the border and even conquered China but they finally switched to Chinese language and culture and completely abandoned their own.

Comment: @user58955: You are talking about the Manchus, who ruled China during the Qing dynasty but ended up utterly assimilating into Chinese culture. The Manchu language is now lost. (But related languages from further afield survive, such as Xibe.)

Comment: @hippietrail There was a period in China called 五胡乱华 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu_Hu_uprising). There was also a Jurchen dynasty, whose rulers and upper class were sinicized in the end.

Comment: @user58955 The Jürchen... weren't they the ancestors of the Manchus, before they changed name? I remember the Kitans (a Mongolic people) also conquered Northern China at one point.

Comment: @JoePineda Yes, but they weren't sinicized as much as Jurchens -- I suppose they were still far to the north from the central China. In the end they lost a war to the Jurchens and the Khitan empire ended.

Comment: @user58955 Very nice example! Thank you very much!

Comment: A European parallel to the Manchus are the Vikings in Normandy, who abandoned their native Norse for French. (It's not quite true that "The Manchu language is now lost" -- there are a handful of speakers left, and Xibe with 40,000 speakers seems to be basically the same language.)

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples of languages spreading more through cultural influence than through the force of arms: [Koine Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek) is an important cultural example for Western civilization. However, Koine Greek wouldn't have spread so quickly through Asia Minor without the conquests of Alexander. Likewise, the Louisiana purchase arguably reflects at least partly the vast military imbalance between France and the United States (just look at what happened to Texas and California). If you want a clear cut example of a language undergoing a radical evolution purely under cultural influence, you can look at the evolution of prehistoric Japanese to [Old Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese) to [Early Middle Japanese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Early_Middle_Japanese) under the influence of Chinese (mostly through the spread of Buddhism). The grammar, lexicon and phonology of the Japanese language changed quite radically in a century or so in order to incorporate the cultural, literary and religious influence of China. No military component at all was involved.

Comment: How did the Japanese phonology change to incorporate the Chinese influences?

Comment: @user58955 Check out the Wikipedia links, or for instance http://www.temcauley.staff.shef.ac.uk/lojphon.shtml

Answer (score 1):

There were some towns in Northern Australia and Eastern New Guinea where the native Austronesian peoples switched from their native languages to Polinesian so as to better comunicate with the sea-faring traders (who were usually Polinesians).

Swahili also expanded enormously in Eastern Africa once it became perceived as a language of trade, reaching far away from the area where the Swahili people (with their mixed Bantu-Arab heritage) natively resided. Though in Swahili's case its expansion meant it was "added" to the languages the villagers' merchants (usually polyglots) would learn, as opposed to obliterating them.

Comment: Downvote: there are no towns in 'Northern Australia' which have native Austronesian people; Polynesian (not 'Polinesian) languages *are* Austronesian, constituting a low-level group within that language family.

Comment: The closest you could get might be the Meriam Islanders in the Torres Strait, who speak the only Papuan language of Australia. Or the Tiwi Islanders who apparently may have acquired numeracy from a northern seafaring people they traded with.

Comment: That was a harsh downvote. I gave a plus because of Swahili. Although I knew this, I didn't remember it. Thanks!

Comment: @Midas Well, they seemed major errors to me. On a par with say, referring to 'the native Berber-speaking towns in southern Ireland', and saying that 'the native Indo-European peoples switched from their native languages to German'.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Constructive criticism is always appreciated, thanks. Will check my books to look for that people I remember once I read about, north of Oz, who switched language due to trading with another, sea-faring people (thanks for the tip, hippietrail!). I must be more careful to check sources before and not fast and furiously type what I remember from memory. If I can't, will delete that part to leave only the reference to Swahili.